# Erlang change VM process initial size. Tune Erlang VM

Tags: memory, process, erlang, server

First I have to mention that I run on a CentOS 7 tuned up to support 1 million connections. I tested with a simple C server and client and I connected 512000 clients. I could have connect more but I did not have enought RAM to spawn more linux client machines, since from a machine I can open 65536 connections; 8 machines * 64000 connections each = 512000.

I made a simple Erlang server to which I want to connect 1 million or half a million clients, using the same C client. The problem I'm having now is memory related. For each successfully `gen_tcp:accept` call I spawn a process. Around 50000 open connections costs me 3.7 GB RAM on server, meanwhile using the C server I could have open 512000 connections using 1.9 GB RAM. It is true that on the C server I did not created a process after accept to handle stuff, I just called accept again in while loop, but even so... guys on web did this erlang thing with less memory ( ejabberd riak  )

I presume that the flags that I pass to the erlang VM should do the trick. From what I read in documentation and on the web this is what I have: 
`erl +K true +Q 64200 +P 134217727 -env ERL_MAX_PORTS 40960000 -env ERTS_MAX_PORTS 40960000 +a 16 +hms 1024 +hmbs 1024`

This is the server code, I open 1 listener that monitors port 5001 by calling `start(1, 5001)`.

```
start(Num,LPort) ->
  case gen_tcp:listen(LPort,[{reuseaddr, true},{backlog,9000000000}]) of
    {ok, ListenSock} ->
      start_servers(Num,ListenSock),
      {ok, Port} = inet:port(ListenSock),
      Port;
    {error,Reason} ->
      {error,Reason}
  end.

start_servers(0,_) ->
  ok;
start_servers(Num,LS) ->
  spawn(?MODULE,server,[LS,0]),
  start_servers(Num-1,LS).

server(LS, Nr) ->
  io:format("before accept ~w~n",[Nr]),
  case gen_tcp:accept(LS) of
    {ok,S} ->
      io:format("after accept ~w~n",[Nr]),
      spawn(ex,server,[LS,Nr+1]),
      proc_lib:hibernate(?MODULE, loop, [S]);
    Other ->
      io:format("accept returned ~w - goodbye!~n",[Other]),
      ok
  end.

loop(S) ->
  ok = inet:setopts(S,[{active,once}]),
  receive
    {tcp,S, _Data} ->
      Answer = 1, % Not implemented in this example
      gen_tcp:send(S,Answer),
      proc_lib:hibernate(?MODULE, loop, [S]);
    {tcp_closed,S} ->
      io:format("Socket ~w closed [~w]~n",[S,self()]),
      ok
  end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Given this configuration your my beam consumed about `2.5 GB` of memory just on start without even your module loaded.

However, if you reduce maximum number of processes to the reasonable value, like `+P 60000` for 50 000 connections test, memory consumption drops rapidly.

With 60 000 processes limit VM only used `527MB` of virtual memory on start.

I've tried to reproduce your test, but unfortunately I was only able to launch  30 000 `netcat`'s on my system before running out of memory (because of client jobs). However I only observed increase of VM memory consumption up to `570MB`.

So my suggestion is that your numbers come from high startup memory consumption and not great number of opened connections. Even then you actually should pay attention to the stats change along with increasing number of opened connections and not absolute values.

### I finally used the following configuration for my benchmark:

> erl +K true +Q 64200 **+P 60000** -env ERL_MAX_PORTS 40960000 -env ERTS_MAX_PORTS 40960000 +a 16 +hms 1024 +hmbs 1024

So I've launched clients with the command

> ```
> for i in `seq 1 50000`; do nc 127.0.0.1 5001 &  done
> ```

Comment: can you please paste me the command to start erlang that you used? erl and what args exactly; also how you made those connections? from inside erlang, C client? I made a C client

Answer (score 0):

Apart from tunes you already made you can adjust tcp buffers as well. By default they take OS default values, but you can pass `{recbuf, Size}`and `{sndbuf, Size}` to `gen_tcp:listen`. It may reduce memory footprints significantly.

Comment: forgot to mention, these options are documented in `inet` module.